# Advanced array_key_exists function

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$test['first']['second']['third']='test';
```

I want to write this functionality:

```
function check_array_key_path_exists($test, $path){
    $path_keys = explode('.', $path);
/*
some code
return true/false
*/
}
```

and i want to see this effects

```
check_array_key_path_exists($test, 'first.second.dog'); //false
check_array_key_path_exists($test, 'first.second'); //true
check_array_key_path_exists($test, 'second'); //false
check_array_key_path_exists($test, 'first.second.third'); //true
check_array_key_path_exists($test, 'first.second.third.dog.cat'); //false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! Here is the code:

```
<?php
$array = [];

$array['first']['second']['third'] = 'test';

function check_array_key_path_exists($array, $path) {
    $pathKeys = explode('.', $path);

    foreach($pathKeys as $pathKey) {
        if(!isset($array[$pathKey])) {
            return false;
        }

        $array = $array[$pathKey];
    }

    return true;
}

if(check_array_key_path_exists($array, 'first.second.third') === false) {
    echo "false";
} else {
    echo "true";
}
```

This prints true. Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: @mariusz Please tick this answer if this satisfied you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to recursively check for each segment of the path. Somehow like this (untested):

```
function array_key_path_exists($array, $path) {
    $split = explode('.', $path, 2);
    if (array_key_exists($array, $split[0])) {
        if (!empty($split[1])) {
            return array_key_path_exists($array[$split[0]], $split[1]);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: define "entirely broken". There might be a typo - as i wrote it is untested, but the logic should be quite clear.

Comment: There are typos and the array_key_exists function is broken.